# Does using 'CAST' keyword to convert a long timestamp to date changes the original data in the database?

Tags: sql

Currently I am working on a database to create reports. I don't want to change anything on the database, I just want to display some part of it according to my task. Here my question is? Does using 'CAST' keyword to convert a long timestamp to date (without time, just date) changes the original data in the database?
Or, is there any other way to convert LONG TIMESTAMP to date.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As long as you're only doing `SELECT`, no `UPDATE` or `INSERT`, nothing's going to be changed in the underlying data. You can safely cast around how ever you pleased.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that you can't really cast a `long` value to a `timestamp`: no, casting only changes the data type at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the data would be to do something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DateFieldName,103) AS "Date" FROM TableName
```

This won't change any of the data, just return the date in the format you would like, the number 103 determines the format, so in this could it would return it in dd/mm/yyyy. You can find a list of codes to return it in the format you like at the following link.

[Link to Codes](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp)

Hope this helps.